# Select Single and Duplicate Row and Return Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently working with my database in SQL Server. I have a table with 23 fields and it has single and duplicate rows. How can I select both of them without having any duplicate data.
I have try this query:

```
 SELECT
     Code, Stuff, and other fields....
     FROM
     (
        SELECT
            *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Code) AS RN
        FROM
            my_table
     )t
     WHERE RN = 1
```

The above code just return the data from the duplicate rows. But, I want the "single rows" also returned.

This is the illustration.

[image]

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be as simple as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Code, Stuff FROM MyTable
```

Or, just add stuff to the partition by clause:

```
PARTITION BY Code,Stuff ORDER BY Code
```

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't return multiple columns. It just return "Code and Stuff" column. Actually my table has 23 column.

Comment: OK, but how do you want the other 21 columns treated? Which rows do you not want returned? Perhaps just add stuff column to your PARTITION BY statement?

Comment: Opss, I'm sorry. You're right SAS. I just realize that there are some the same codes have the different value in another column. Actually the solution just Distinct Code, Stuff. But, the problem only how to distinct Stuff (Varchar Datatype)?

Comment: NP, the distinct will select distinct combinations on both columns. The problem is how to handle the rest of your columns, that you have to specify..

Comment: I don't care the rest of the columns. I just need the distinct Code and Stuff. I try this "SELECT DISTINCT Code, CAST(Stuff as NVARCHAR(MAX)) FROM mytable". But it still return duplicate rows. Any idea?

Comment: OK, then just "SELECT DISTINCT Code, Stuff FROM MyTable should" work. Perhaps there are trailing spaces.. "SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(Code) AS Code, RTRIM(Stuff) AS Stuff FROM MyTable"

Comment: Excellent! Always those trailing spaces... :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

You may need to add Stuff and more fields in **Partition BY**

```
 SELECT
     Code, Stuff
     FROM
     (
        SELECT
            *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code,Stuff ORDER BY Code) AS RN
        FROM
            my_table
     )t
     WHERE RN = 1
```